# Android Things disable mouse cursor in touch screen

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I use a touch screen 5 inch(800*480) tft LCD HDMI with raspberry pi 3 ,
I use this [driver](https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/touchinputdisplaydriver).
The touch driver works and emits points but shows the mouse cursor in the display. How so I disable the mouse cursor on the touch screen?
below picture show my problem .
[image: sample app]

OS Version:

```
1.0.12.5501548
```

My `config.txt` in boot files  is:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

When I add below config to `config.txt` mouse cursor disappeared but the driver doesn't work also.

```
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
```

Comment: That's also unexpected behavior. I usually never have a mouse cursor unless one is connected over USB.

Comment: @NickFelker i add picture to question and doesn't connect any USB Cable to raspberry Pi